# SharePoint Approval Workflow Issue

Tags: workflow, approval

I have created a SharePoint Approval workflow and coming across an issue.

The wiki page goes to a team for approval which works fine, someone in the team then reviews it and makes changes where appropriate.

The problem is when the approver makes those changes, it starts the workflow again as if they were submitting / amending the page.

I want to stop this from happening. So I want them to be able to make changes as part of the approval workflow without causing the workflow to start all over again.

Answer (score 1):

Is this an out-of-the box workflow? If so, you can't change it.

If not, you probably start the workflow on item changed. And if somebody changes the page, the workflow should start again.

What you could do is add a column where you flag if the workflow has started and check that before starting a new approval workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change the start options for the Workflow, maybe let it start manually once a new page is created and not on every revision for the Page.